# chroot() with clone() not functioning correctly

Tags: c, linux, containers, clone, chroot

I'm trying to use the chroot() syscall with clone() in order to create some sort of a container with UTS namespace isolation.

My code is as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1073741824
static char stack[STACK_SIZE];

int callFunc() {
    char *args[3];
    chdir("..");
    chdir("ubuntu-root");

    args[0] = "/bin/bash";
    args[1] = "-i";
    args[2] = NULL;
    int f = chroot(".");
    if (f == -1) {
        printf("problem in chroot\n");
    }
    chdir("/");
    printf("I'm root\n");
    int t = execv("/bin/bash", args);

    if (t == -1) {
        printf("bash failed\n");
    }


}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    int flags;
    flags =  CLONE_NEWUTS | SIGCHLD;
    //flags = 0;
    //callFunc();

    int r = clone(callFunc, stack + STACK_SIZE, flags, NULL);
    if (r == -1) {
        printf("clone failed\n");
    }

        return 0;

}
```

the "ubuntu-root" folder contains ubuntu base rootfs from their website.

When I run my code without clone() it runs fine, but when I use clone for the isolation I only get the "I'm root" print and then the program exit.

I always run the program as root so that is not the issue(I hope).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you want to use `waitpid()` or something like that to keep the parent alive while the child runs?  As it stands, the parent will exit.  The child will keep going and will presumably move to the jail and start the shell, but you can't interact with a shell that is in the background.

Comment: I will try the waitpid(), thanks!

Comment: echo $$ prints the same both before and after' so I think its indeed exiting

Comment: regarding:  ` int f = chroot(".");
    if (f == -1) {
        printf("problem in chroot\n");
    }  ... printf("I'm root\n");`  If there was  a problem with the call to `chroot()`, then the statement: `printf("problem in chroot\n");`  will be wrong.  Suggest, if the call to `chroot()` fails, to suceed, then call `perror( "problem in chroot" );  followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `int t = execv("/bin/bash", args);

    if (t == -1) {
        printf("bash failed\n");
    }`  the correct sequence is:  `execv("/bin/bash", args);  perror( "execv for bash failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling: `chdir()`, always check (==0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==-1) then call `perror( "chdir failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) The posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS of warnings, including: "untitled1.c:32:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]" for the function: `callFunc()`

Comment: from the `clone()` man page:  "Only   a   privileged   process   (CAP_SYS_ADMIN)   can   employ
              CLONE_NEWUTS."